# Validate the contents of XML while deserializing using Xstream

Tags: java, xml, validation, deserialization, xstream

What is the best way to validate the contents of XML while deserializing using XStream library?

```
<MessageRequest>  
    <destinationIDs>12345</destinationIDs>  
    <destinationType>Site</destinationType>    
    <messageName>C:\runShell.jsp</messageName>  
    <messageLen>1268</messageLen>
</MessageRequest>
```

For example in the above XML if the "messageName" contains any invalid data like a file path (C:\runshell.jsp) I should not process this request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an xsd schema to validate specific tags from xml.

The tag inside xsd file should contain a regex with restricted chars or pattern type and should be like:

```
<xs:simpleType name="messageName">   
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">       
        <xs:pattern value="[^r]*"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

*replace r with chars you want to exclude.